# How do I effectively use OG tags in LinkedIn to style URL's in a post

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a client who posts her website URL in a LinkedIn message and in emails and she wants it styled a certain way. I have figured out how to use OG meta tags to accomplish everything except the image she wants in URL display. Right now LinkedIn is sourcing the image from the home page. It's too big. I want a smaller logo aligned to the right of the box where the URL is displayed. I have no experience with this so any help would be appreciated.

I have tried using the img OG meta tag and that is not working. It is overridden somehow. The image displayed in the LinkedIn post inspector is the logo from the landing page. That would be OK if I could significantly reduce it in size and align it to the right. The URL and Title meta tags are working fine.

Thanks